# How can I resolve redis Python type of json is partially unknown?

Tags: python, python-3.x, redis

Python currently recognizes my Redis client's JSON member as partially unknown:

```py
val = self.client.json(encoder=json.dumps, decoder=json.loads)
# Type of "json" is partially unknown
# Type of "json" is "(encoder: Unknown = ..., decoder: Unknown = ...) -> JSON"
```

What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a type hint issue. If you wanted to, you could change your signature so that json.dumps was a json.dumps: str, given that json.dumps returns a string.

Ideally the library would define these things in its signature, for all functions, and you'd get the type hints assistance.